# Query a document on array elements in MongoDB using Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I am new to MongoDB. My sample document is

```
{
    "Notification" : [
        {
            "date_from" : ISODate("2013-07-08T18:30:00Z"),
            "date_too" : ISODate("2013-07-30T18:30:00Z"),
            "description" : "fdfd",
            "url" : "www.adf.com"
        },
        {
            "date_from" : ISODate("2013-07-01T18:30:00Z"),
            "date_too" : ISODate("2013-07-30T18:30:00Z"),
            "description" : "ddddddddddd",
            "url" : "www.pqr.com"
        }
    ],
```

I am trying to update the Notification whose `"url" : "www.adf.com"`. My Java code to do this is:

```
BasicDBObject query=new BasicDBObject("url","www.adf.com");

DBCursor f = con.coll.find(query);
```

It does not search for the document whose `"url"` is `"www.adf.com"`.

Comment: con is connection object

Comment: coll is DBCollection object.

Comment: You forgot the `Notification` in your query. You have to query for `Notification.url`.

Comment: @obecker Notification is array not nested doc. I also tried it BasicDBObject query=new BasicDBObject("Notification.url","www.adf.com");

Comment: see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations/ -> Arrays
The nested object syntax should work also for arrays.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have a nested document in this case. Your document has a field `Notification` which is an array storing multiple sub-objects with the field `url`. To search in a sub-field, you need to use the dot-syntax:

```
BasicDBObject query=new BasicDBObject("Notification.url","www.adf.com");
```

This will, however, return the whole document with the whole `Notification` array. You likely only want the sub-document. To filter this, you need to use [the two-argument version of Collection.find](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/).

```
BasicDBObject query=new BasicDBObject("Notification.url","www.example.com");
BasicDBObject fields=new BasicDBObject("Notification.$", 1);

DBCursor f = con.coll.find(query, fields);
```

[The `.$` means "only the first entry of this array which is matched by the find-operator"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/positional/#proj._S_)

This should still return one document with a sub-array `Notifications`, but this array should only contain the entry where `url == "www.example.com"`.

To traverse this document with Java, do this:

```
BasicDBList notifications = (BasicDBList) f.next().get("Notification"); 
BasicDBObject notification = (BasicDBObject) notifications.get(0);
String url = notification.get("url");
```

**By the way:** When your database grows you will likely run into performance problems, unless you create an index to speed up this query:

```
con.coll.ensureIndex(new BasicDBObject("Notification.url", 1));
```

Comment: When I tried to access "url" seprated by above query             String s=(String) f.curr().get("url");  It returns null value

Comment: @PrashantThorat That's likely because the returned document has no field `url`. It likely only has a field `Notifications` which contains a DBList which contains one DBObject which contains a field `url`. Check it in the debugger.

Comment: @PrashantThorat `f.curr().get("Notifications").get(0).get("url")` could work.

Comment: Is their any other alternative? I tried it but it gives error at get(0)

Comment: @PrashantThorat Sorry, but I lost my tarot deck. Please use the debugger and tell me what document `f.curr()` returns.

Comment: f.curr() returns    { "Notification" : [ { "date_from" : { "$date" : "2013-07-01T18:30:00.000Z"} , "date_too" : { "$date" : "2013-07-29T18:30:00.000Z"} , "description" : "ssssssssssssssssss" , "url" : "www.example.com"}] , "_id" : { "$oid" : "51ed1cc2e4b07014f1170b9f"}}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34228/discussion-between-prashant-thorat-and-philipp)

Comment: added results of the chat discussion to answer

Comment: Note: mongodb introduced a method findAndModify that seems to simplify the update: http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#findAndModify%28com.mongodb.DBObject,%20com.mongodb.DBObject,%20com.mongodb.DBObject,%20boolean,%20com.mongodb.DBObject,%20boolean,%20boolean%29