# How can I find selected array elements from mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java

I want to find only select array elements from a mongo document.like in following document I want to return only hard questions from array.
am using mongo driver for java.

```
BasicDBObject query=new BasicDBObject("questionList.type", "hard");
DBCursor curssc  = collection.find(query);
```

Document

```
{
   "testpaperid": 1,
   "testpaperNo": "science",
   "questionList":
      [
         {
            "question": "this is question no 1",
            "type": "hard"
         },
         {
            "question": "this is question no 2",
            "type":"simple"
         },
         {
            "question": "this is question no 3",
            "type": "hard"
         }
      ] 
}
```

Comment: try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873917/find-query-on-array-ellements-in-mongodb-using-java

Answer (score 3):

If using  [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) operator it limits the contents of an `<array>` field from the query results to contain only the first element matching the `$elemMatch` condition.

So If you run this query :

```
db.collectionName.find({"questionList":{"$elemMatch":{"type":"hard"}}},{"questionList.type.$":1})
```

and above query equivalent code in java as below :

```
BasicDBObject eleMatch = new BasicDBObject();
eleMatch.put("type", "hard");
BasicDBObject elemMatchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
elemMatchQuery.put("$elemMatch", eleMatch);
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("questionList", elemMatchQuery);
BasicDBObject projection = new BasicDBObject();
projection.put("questionList.type.$", 1);
DBCollection dbcoll = mongoTemplate.getCollection("collectionName");
DBObject object = dbcoll.find(query, projection);
```

This return only first matching `type:hard` output contains `"questionList" : [ { "question" : "this is question no 1", "type" : "hard" } ]` not all  `questionList` array which contains `type:hard`

For avoiding this should use [mongo java aggregation driver](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/getting-started/quick-tour/) and mongo aggregation query looks like :

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
  "$unwind": "$questionList"
}, {
  "$match": {
    "questionList.type": "hard"
  }
}, {
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "testpaperid": {
      "$first": "$testpaperid"
    },
    "testpaperNo": {
      "$first": "$testpaperNo"
    },
    "questionList": {
      "$push": "$questionList"
    }
  }
}).pretty()
```

and this aggregation query in java as below :

```
// unwind  questionList
DBObject unwind = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$questionList");
// create  pipeline operations, with the $match
DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("questionList.type", "hard"));
// Now the $group operation  
DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject("_id", "$group field");
groupFields.put("testpaperid", new BasicDBObject("$first", "$testpaperid"));
groupFields.put("testpaperNo", new BasicDBObject("$first", "$testpaperNo"));
groupFields.put("questionList", new BasicDBObject("$push", "$questionList"));
DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);
// run aggregation
List < DBObject > pipeline = Arrays.asList(unwind, match, group);
AggregationOutput output = collectionName.aggregate(pipeline);
for(DBObject result: output.results()) {
  System.out.println(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use [array operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query-array/) in a regular query in MongoDB, it returns the documents that match the query criteria, and return the whole document, including the contents of the array field. This means that you cannot filter out some documents from an array field using a regular query.

But you can do that using the [aggregation query](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/). The following query is an aggregation query for mongo-shell, which you can easily translate to Java driver code:

```
db.quest.aggregate(
   [
      {$unwind: '$questionList'}, 
      {$match: {'questionList.type': 'hard'}}, 
      {$group: 
         {
            _id: {
                    _id: '$_id', 
                    testpaperid: '$testpaperid', 
                    testpaperNo: '$testpaperNo'
                 }, 
            questionList: {$push: '$questionList'}
          }
       }, 
       {$project: {
                     _id: '$_id._id', 
                     testpaperid: '$_id.testpaperid', 
                     testpaperNo: '$_id.testpaperNo', 
                     questionList: 1
                  }
       }
   ]
)
```